# Is $x+1 \in (x^2+2x+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

I am familiar with examples of a ideal like $4Z$, but I can't think what a ideal generated by a polynomial is like. I.e. if the polynomial functions vanishing on a vanishing set of an ideal are radicals of the ideal, I should look at the ideal generated by the polynomial function where that $=0$.. * $k[x] = \mathbb{C}[x]$..

If the ideal (not of functions vanishing on this ideal $\sqrt{I}$, just the polynomials functions ${I}$ in the ideal generated by the polynomial) is generated by $x^{2} +2x+1$ can someone answer if $x+1$ is in that ideal, and just
*enumerate* some elements !?!?

I have used wolframalpha to solve $(x^{2} +2x+1) y = x+1$, the answer is $x(x+1)$, but I still can not tell if $x+1 \in I$.

Comment: The ideal of $\mathbb C[x]$ generated by the polynomial $x^2+2x+1=(x+1)^2$ contains all polynomials in $\mathbb C[x]$ with $(x+1)^2$ as a factor.

Comment: So that means the ideal is so much different $| \mathbb{V}$?

Comment: Different than what?

Comment: $(x+1)^2$ doesn't appear to be a factor of $(x+1)$ so that means the ideal $I (x^2+2x+1) \neq I (x^2+2x+1) |_{\mathbb{V}(x^2+2x+1)}$....

Comment: The ideal generated by a polynomial of degree $d$ consists of polynomials of degree $\ge d$.

Comment: $0$ doesn't have a degree $\ge d$.

Comment: I do not understand your notation. What is $\mathbb V(x^2+2x+1)$? Is it the variety defined by $x^2+2x+1$? Or the variety of the ideal generated by $x^2+2x+1$? Or something else? What does the symbol "$|$" in your last comment mean? Usually it stands for restriction, but how does an ideal, whose elements are polynomials, restrict to a set whose elements are complex numbers?

Comment: The vanishing set of this function is $x=-1$ . The polynomials restricted to that vanishing set are a radical ideal, so $(x+1)$ is in that ideal (the vanishing of $(x+1)$ also is $-1$. However $(x+1) $ isnt in the ideal generated by $x^2+2x+1$ without evaluation on the variety $V=-1$. . . . anyway I was just thinking about what the group is looking like just by addition and I think i figured out that is elements like $2(x^2+2x+1)$ and $-1(x^2+2x+1)$ and so on (and then more by multiplying with the other elements. . .